# Graphics abnormally init on 14.04 and live CD

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

My desktop first failed to load unity, which doesn't repair with tries to reinstall unity and ubuntu-desktop. I couldn't configure them seems like lack of a proper driver. When I had a look at nvidia drivers, things seemed more strange: I didn't have nvidia drivers, neither checking by `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` nor `update-alternatives` for graphics driver, which said, I had only one option that is the default ubuntu driver.

But I knew I had cuda development tools installed on the desktop and I worked with GPU feature to accelerate a Python module's calculations. Cuda installed corresponding drivers at that time. When I had a look at cuda, the files are there, but I failed to test my script: `modprobe: no nvidia module found`.

The only thing I did before that happened, was boot into Windows 7 about to edit a word file. Maybe, there something else happened, but I didn't know because I wasn't always in front of my desktop. When I came back, unity dropped in infinite loop. And I didn't succeed to repair. That's another long story.

Even tried to revert system back with `timeshift` won't help me. I had backups, but they failed with same problem. And finally, when I boot with live CD again (before that I used it to restore system, it worked fine):

[image: graphics driver fail, red flashing dashes on screen]

**Update**:

Booted again to fetch the Xorg log file screen-related part:

```
...
[    20.974] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr 16 11:21:21 2015
[    20.990] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    21.075] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    21.075] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    21.075] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    21.075] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    21.076] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
...
[    21.880] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    21.880] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    21.880] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    21.880] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    21.880] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
# other modules loaded successfully
...
```

The odd part is what happened to a fresh liveCD. Firmware incompatibility? Why I didn't have the problem before.